# sql: How to check a zipcode is exist in zipcode range

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a a database with zipcode range:

```
id  name    zip_start   zip_end
1   A       1212        1216
2   B       9100        9201
```

Now I want to check any number is exist within the zipcode range.
How can I write the sql for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try where greater and less then

```
WHERE `zip_start` >= '$zip' AND `zip_end` <= '$zip'
```

or between

```
WHERE '$zip' between `zip_start` AND `zip_end`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set @searchedZip = 1214;

select *
from zipCodes
where @searchedZip between zip_start and zip_end
```